# Blade - Mostrar array multidimensional en vista

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy tratando de mostrar un array multidimensional con blade en la vista (pregunta aleatoria según $random). Lo intento de esta manera, pero de momento muestra todo el array y no el aleatorio:

Blade en vista:

```
@foreach($preguntas as $p)
    {{$p['pregunta']}}<br>
    {{$p['respuesta1']}}<br>
    @endforeach
```

Array + random + envio a vista:

```
    $preguntas=[
                0=>[
                    'pregunta'=>'perro',
                    'respuesta1'=>'txakurra'
                ],
                1=>[
                    'pregunta'=>'gato',
                    'respuesta1'=>'katua'
                ],
                2=>[
                    'pregunta'=>'pájaro',
                    'respuesta1'=>'txoria'
                ],
                3=>[
                    'pregunta'=>'caballo',
                    'respuesta1'=>'zaldia'
                ],
            ];
$rand=rand(0,3);

return view('pregunta')->with('preguntas',$preguntas)->with('rand',$rand);
```

Comment: en el return envio un rand0,3) en la variable $rand. El foreach recorre todo, cierto. ¿Cómo se muestra un contenido concreto del array multidimensional? algo así como {{$preguntas[$random]['pregunta']}} No lo se.

Comment: ya funciona perfecto!

Comment: si conseguiste la respuesta, puedes agregarla, aceptarla y recibir puntuación positiva por parte de la comunidad indicando como lo resolviste

Comment: La respuesta es la indicada en la pregunta (Está corregida). {{$preguntas[$rand]['pregunta']}}

Comment: revertí tu edición, te comento de acuerdo con [answer], tu aporte debe ir en la zona de respuestas y no en la pregunta